# Gradually opening html form

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

A little web design dilemma: I have a form with a lot of options, mainly radio buttons but not only.

I want the form to open up gradually, meaning at the beginning only two radio buttons are visible, and after the user picks one, more options appear under the chosen radio button. If the user then switches the pick, the page updates and shows the options under the new pick.

This happens on several levels, say 4 or 5 levels, and at the end there is a submit button that submits only certain inputs according to the branches the user chose. Also some of the branches have identical components even though the initial choice was different.

These are the options I could think of:

1. Build the complete form in the html body and use jquery to hide and show them according to the choices of the user. This means I have to write sections that repeat themselves twice.
2. Write nothing in the body, and append new elements when the user makes certain choices. This means the JavaScript is more complicated, because I have to make sure nothing appends twice.
3. Write an HTML skeleton of the form, and use append to fill it. Then use jquery to show and hide elements. This has none of the disadvantages but seems a bit unaesthetic.

Which one should I pick? Any better ideas?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably going to use http://wiki.jqueryui.com/w/page/12137997/Menu
or JStree (http://www.jstree.com/) which I found out about from here http://wiki.jqueryui.com/w/page/12138128/Tree

Answer (score 0):

It really comes down to your knowledge of javascript. The cleanest way would be to append to form using javascript. This way you can avoid having duplicates in your form.

If you are not that familiar with javascript and don't know how to append the form, then I would use javascript to show/hide the different parts of the form.

I think using javascript to append would be the correct way, but I don't see anything really wrong with using javascript to just hide parts of the form.